# Watchify + tsify + Visual Studio == stale code

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify, watchify, tsify

We are running a Gulp task inside of Visual Studio (2015) to execute watchify.  Works great some of the time, but sometimes watchify builds old code.

Repro:

- Modify a .ts file in Visual Studio
- Save
- In the Task Runner Explorer, watch for watchify output, indicating that it ran (it does)
- Refresh Chrome/clear cache (I use the "disable caching while debug window is open" option in Chrome)
- View source in the Chrome Debugger (a little less than half the time, it will be the old code)

Any idea what I need to look for?  Note that if I execute a full browserify build, Chrome always sees the new code -- this staleness problem only happens when Watchify is in the mix.

Comment: When you next have stale code in the browser, you should check to see whether the on-disk bundle contains stale code. If the code within it isn't stale, it's not a watchify problem.

Comment: It's not stale code in the browser -- I'm making sure to clear the cache or disable caching.

Comment: It's possible to enable a substantial amount of logging within tsify [using the `NODE_DEBUG` environment variable](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#debugging). Looking for differences in logged output between builds in which it works and does not works is likely the best (only?) approach.

Comment: I can try that.  To be honest, I'm not sure whether this is a tsify problem or a watchify problem (tsify seems to work fine if I invoke "full build" by executing browserify.  I think that seems to indicate watchify as the problem.

Comment: Seems like it is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788166/browserify-watchify-compile-old-ressource-on-localhost-with-vuecomponent