# Browserify watchify compile old ressource on localhost with VueComponent

Tags: vue.js, browserify, watchify

I'm pretty new on compiler and npm command.

I use this starter for a project https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify-simple

I served my project and I was working on when I update a script (I'm working with Single File Component - VueJS) and now the output "dist.js" is still in error due to old script.
I have reinstall, create a new project, I copy my new sources and when I launch the command "npm run dev" I have the same error due to script which does't exist anymore.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.values (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:8080/dist/build.js:35858:32
at Array.filter (native)
at VueComponent.userLigues
```

"VueCompnent.userLigues" doesn't exist anymore in my new code.

That's a real problem I have to solve for tomorrow night :(

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Seems like it is related to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595475/watchify-tsify-visual-studio-stale-code